# SPECファイル内でのオプション値に反映される優先順位

Tags: apache

Apache2.4のデフォルトのSPECファイルだと以下のオプションが定義されています。

```
%configure \
   --enable-layout=RPM \
   --libdir=%{_libdir} \
   ...
```

このとき、config.layout内にもlibdirの定義があり、configureのオプション内にも定義があります。
優先されるのはどちらの内容となるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.layout` 中の値は無指定時デフォルト値
`configure` にオプションを明示したらデフォルト値を上書き
です。つまり手指定オプションのほうが強いッス。

普通にソースコードをコンパイルするユーザは `apache2.spec` を使わないので無視してよい
だったはず (`apache2.spec` は Apache httpd のデベロッパが使うもの)